Can't get access to local nginx with NAT and NSX Router
I have small lab at VMware cloud director. I configured SNAT {public_ip}->192.168.100.0/24 any protocol any port. Then i configured DNAT (firstly 192.168.100.22->{public_ip}, tcp protocol, source port 22 and 80 at second rule, well dest ip's 22 and 80), secondary tried to forward ALL ports and protocols but still nothing. Ssh is working ok, but not nginx. I used name_server localhost, 192.168.100.2, {public_ip} - nothing works, still closed 80 port at target. I checked firewall but default_policy is accept and moreover i added the rule to allow 80 port at {public ip}, also tried to allow all - nothing helped. Where i did the misstake? I can give logs or configs if needed.
